# What is the subscript of the max notiation stating?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, linear-programming

I am a physics graduate interested in moving into the field of AI. My knowledge of pure maths is limited, leading to difficulties in even understanding notation in the subject.

I do not understand what the writing under the max statement is trying to indicate in the following expression:

$\tilde{U}_i (p_i)=\text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M U_i (\vec{p}) $

where directly beneath the $\text{max}$ statement there is written:

$\vec{p}-i$

The context is that of solving a DCOP using the max-sum algorithm to find the optimal actions for a set of agents. $U_i$ is the utility function of agent $i$, which depends on $\vec{p}$, the set of decision variables of the agents that agent $i$'s utility function depends on. The paper can be found here for more context.

http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/267268/1/paper.pdf

Comment: I suggest you to ask the authors. This notation is really weird in my opinion.